# MongoDB docker image connection issue

Tags: mongodb, docker

Im try to run a local docker container running MongoDB but I got some issues.
Im using MacOS and this is my docker file:

```
FROM mongo:4.4.10

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y mongodb-database-tools

ENV MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME admin
ENV MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD admin

EXPOSE 27017

CMD ["mongod", "--bind_ip_all"]
```

But when I try to connect in mongo inside the container I got:

```bash
root@1820984d904c:/# mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.4.10
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

Im running the container like this:

```bash
docker run -it -p 27017:27017 --rm --name containername imagename bash
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: How do you start the container?  How are you getting that shell?

Comment: this is the command Im using: 
docker run -it -p 27017:27017 --rm --name containername imagename bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not starting mongo with your `docker run` command. You are starting `bash` instead.

From https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#overriding-dockerfile-image-defaults:

> **CMD (default command or options)**
>
> Recall the optional COMMAND in the Docker commandline:
>
> ```
> docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]
> ```
>
> This command is optional because the person who created the IMAGE may have already provided a default COMMAND using the Dockerfile CMD instruction. As the operator (the person running a container from the image), you can override that CMD instruction just by specifying a new COMMAND.

So start your docker with

```
docker run -p 27017:27017 --rm --name containername imagename
```

Then bash in to the container with

```
docker exec -it containername bash
```